# Массив javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
        <div id="tabs_index">
            <ul id="icon_block">
                <li class="auto"><a name="auto" href="#auto"></a></li>
                <li class="general"><a name="general" href="#general"></a></li>
                <li class="general2"><a name="general2" href="#general2"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наводке курсора на li, его class добавлялся в массив, и чтобы все элементы которые добавляются в массив были уникальными, то есть чтобы допустим class="auto"/"general"/"general2" добавлялся в массив только один раз? Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: если нужна уникальность - то следует использовать идентификаторы, а не классы

Comment: А можно примерчик?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть не самое элегантное решение и уж точно не самое оптимальное по ресурсам.

```
$(function(){
        var mass = [];
        $('#icon_block').on('hover', 'li', function(){
            var li_class = $(this).attr('class');
            var flag = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
                if(mass[i] === li_class) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) { 
                mass.push(li_class);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: if(!Array.prototype.indexOf) { // если не ошибаюсь, IE 7, 8
      Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
          if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
        }
        return -1;
      }
    }
    // ....
    if(!!~mass.indexOf(li_class)) {
      // ...
    }

Comment: Класное решение, возьму на заметку.